# WHERE clause date is greater than 24h - Carbon / Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I Am making a query where I need to find all the results for reminder that are greater than 24h in that database.

My query looks like this but its wrong I believe

```
$reminder = Reminder::where('reminder_date','<', Carbon::now()->addHours(24))
                          ->get();
```

Using Laravel / Carbon

Comment: Is the field reminder_date in the type of date or datetime?

Comment: it is a datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might be using the wrong operator. `<` (Less than) should be swapped for `>` (Greater than):

```
$reminder = Reminder::where('reminder_date','>', Carbon::now()->addHours(24))
                      ->get();
```